# -end index in lsearch in tcl

Tags: tcl

The `lsearch` command has [`-start index`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.4/TclCmd/lsearch.htm#M18) as one of the options

> **-start** *index* The list is searched starting at position *index*. If *index* has the value **end**, it refers to the last element in the list, and
>   **end-***integer* refers to the last element in the list minus the specified
>   integer offset.

I would like to use `-end` along with `-start`. How can it be done?
It can be done by discarding the indices greater than or equal to `-end` index in the `lsearch` returned list. But is there any better way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd be tempted in your case to use `lrange` to produce a copy of the list being searched without the elements you don't want returned.

```
lsearch [lrange $theList $start $end] $searchTerm
```

The real purpose of the `-start` option is to allow skipping over previously-found matches, and it is less useful now that we have the `-all` option (which makes `lsearch` return a list of *all* the places where it can match the search term). It was used a bit like this:

```
for {set idx -1} {[set idx [lsearch -start [incr idx] $list $term]] >= 0} {} {
    # Process the match index...
    puts "found $term at $idx"
}
```

And now you'd write:

```
foreach idx [lsearch -all $list $term] {
    puts "found $term at $idx"
}
```